Module "firebase/auth" has no exported member 'signInWithPopup'
I'm attempting to use the popup signin with google on react native + expo project but i can't import the method. I was reading the firebase changelog and the method is seemingly not deprecated.
import { router } from 'expo-router';
import {
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    User,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithCredential,
    signInWithPopup, // I got the error here
    signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';

package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
  "expo": "^51.0.8",
  "expo-application": "~5.9.1",
  "expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
  "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
  "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.14",
  "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
  "expo-image": "~1.12.9",
  "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
  "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
  "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
  "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
  "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
  "firebase": "^10.11.1",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.74.1",
  "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
  "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
  "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
  "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
  "jest": "^29.2.1",
  "jest-expo": "~51.0.2",
  "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
  "typescript": "~5.3.3"
},


signInWithPopup is a method expected to be used by a browser.  React-Native is NOT a browser....it is a "native app".
If you are trying to authenticate via a "native app" with Google auth, then you will want to use react-native-firebase instead of the Firebase Web Client SDK (firebase).
I wrote about the differences between these two libraries in this article.

Hi Greg! Thank you for your answer. I really know that but i'm using react native web. It's technically web. For ios and android i'm currently using another approach that is working, i'm looking for a module that provides the whole thing for ios-android-web

It depends on what you mean by "the whole thing".  There are capabilities in Firebase that require "the native OS", and there are others that can run entirely in JavaScript.  For the ones that require "the native OS" such as AppCheck, Crashlytics, and most of the "social logins" you need to use the native APIs which do not exist in Web.  I don't know of any library that offers use of native capabilities of the phone, web capabilities in a browser, and all "just work".  It think you have to use Platform-conditional code to make this work.

Basically I want to signIn users via popup on web and persist the data. It seems the package installation recognizes in which platform are you developing and install only the compatible code. For example, I installed the firebase package on my RN project and also on another Next Js project, on this last case you can use the signInWithPopup method and not on the RN project, thats the point of the original question.

But you cannot use signInWithPopup() in an RN app.  You can in an RNWeb app, but not an RN-ios or RN-android (or other non-browser, OS-dependent platforms).  To me "RNWeb" is mostly not an RN app.  It uses RN constructs, but ultimately is closer to a React web app than to an RN "native app".  The key in all of this is the term "native".  An RN app on a native platform is not a browser app, and it does not support "popups" via the Firebase Web Client SDK.

I understand that. The only place that I want to use the popup is on the web part of react native (to be used on PCs), but it seems the package doesn't install the method

Please share details of what leads you to the statement that "the package doesn't install the method".  Is there an error message or something?

Hi Greg, there isn't an error installing the package, it's like the package recognizes that im using react-native instead of react, thats because i got "Module "firebase/auth" has no exported member 'signInWithPopup'" the title of the issue

I have the same issue. The thing is though that the Google Sign-in works as expected on the Expo web app. The pop-up window appears and I am able to sign in with Google.
So I import signInWithPopup separately and add @ts-ignore:
import { sendEmailVerification, signInWithEmailAndPassword, User, GoogleAuthProvider, } from "firebase/auth";

// @ts-ignore
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

